# Subclassing a UIViewController that is a chat room to reuse

Tags: ios, parsing, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I built a UIViewController that acts as a chatroom using Parse as a backend using this tutorial: [Chatroom Tutuorial](http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com%22Chatroom%20Tutorial%22)

In my app I have a few levels of table views leading to different categories to chat about. I want to subclass the original chat view controller to use for chatrooms for the other categories (probably around 30) and I'm not sure how. Also, each chat room needs a unique identifier so I can access them on Parse. I can probably figure that out later though. Any help or leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to answer such a vague question. What problems have you encountered trying to subclass you existing controller? What does your implementation look like?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need unique subclasses of your chat view controller for each of your 30 categories. Instead, I'd suggest adding a unique identifier property to the base class, and then setting it when you instantiate one.

Look at how the traits of the different view controllers vary among your categories, and see if they break down into logical family groupings. Say you have a group of chat rooms that need built-in support for emoticons. Then say you have a group of chat rooms that needs to be able to paste small images in-line. Then say you have a third group that needs to support group chatting, where some messages are only sent to a designated group of people in the room.

I'm pulling these traits out of thin air as examples. What matters is, do you have families of chat rooms that have common behaviors/traits unique to that group? If so, it might make sense to make that family of chat rooms a subclass of your base chat room view controller class.